# Prevent Program to close when the process exit C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, process

I have a batch file that i run through process but when the batch file finish running and closed the Form also close. How can i prevent the process in closing the form. Here is the code.

```
Process support = new Process();
                        support.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Support\Support.bat";
                        support.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        support.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        support.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                        support.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                        support.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
                        support.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                        support.Start();
                        support.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Here is the output handler that writes the output of the batchfile to a richTextbox

```
private void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        string line;
        line = (outLine.Data.ToString());
        txtStatus.AppendText(line + "\n");

    }
```

The batch file automatically close when done and the Program close also and never executed the remaining codes.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question. Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: "the form"? That we have no information about, including how it relates to the first block of code.

Comment: Should i post the whole code?

Comment: Maybe it crashes not closes?

Comment: No, you should follow the link to [mcve]. It takes skill and effort to create one, but that skill is an essential debugging skill to learn anyway. It's "I've got some weird behaviour, what's the smallest piece of code that demonstrates that behaviour". It helps you discard irrelevancies that may otherwise distract you because you're "sure" that they must be part of the problem.

Comment: Does the program really close? Did you try to put breakpoint after process is created? For me it seems ok, but if you expect some results produced by the bat file, you should wait until process finishes `Process.WaitForExit()`

Comment: I have tried adding process.waitforexit() but it still close. I cant put a breakpoint because the program should run and tested in another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

or

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

ReadLine() waits for the Enter key to be pressed, while ReadKey() waits for any key to be pressed (Except modifier keys - Shift, Control, Alt, Command, Option.. to name a few)

If this is purely for testing from VS then you can run the app without debugging using Ctrl + F5

Comment: It's a windows form application

Comment: OK, if it's then executing the batch file, depending on what's in the batch file could you not put a 'PAUSE' at the end of it prevent it from closing without intervention?

Comment: It sounds more like it's erroring and closing rather than completing execution - in which case I'd use some breakpoints and debug to figure out where it's going wrong. Does the batch file @ "C:\Support\Support.bat"; exist on the machine you're trying to run this from?

Comment: Unfortunately i am not the one who created the batchfile it executes a lot of commands and exit after executing. Tried to put pause in the end does not work.

Comment: Yes the batchfile exist and i can see the successful result of the batchfile execution (it generate the correct files it needs to generate). The problem is when the batchfile finishes and exits, the form exits too.

Comment: It certainly sounds like the form is exiting due to a error, without proper debugging on your solution it's difficult to tell where it's going wrong. Can you provide any error message?

Comment: There is no error message or any error apear. It just closes.

Answer (score 0):

Process will open up a window by itself, and once the .bat file exits, will exit and close the main window. It's not your code that is wrong, it's by default the way a .bat file is run if you just double-clicked it in Explorer (cmd opens until .bat is completed and then closes again)

You mentioned that you tried "Process.WaitForExit()" but I'd like to point out, in your context, it should be "support.WaitForExit()" much like your "dt.WaitForExit()" (code you posted that is now removed)

If that doesn't work, add "PAUSE" on a new line in your support.bat file. This will prevent the window from closing as well until a key is pressed.

If you do not have access to edit the support.bat file, all you need to do is read the file contents and save it somewhere temporarily, and then run it... or add it:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("support.bat"))
{
  w.WriteLine("PAUSE");
}
```

Above is obviously an example, you'd need to check if "PAUSE" is already the last line before writing to the file again. I also didn't show code on how to create a file and saving it, you should be able to handle that :)

Comment: I tried both. Addidng support.WaitForExit() and adding pause on the end of the batchfile but the output is the same. Here is what happen before that. I execute thw same batch file uaing the same process but not writing the result in the richtextbox and everything is ok. But when i add the code that writes the result in the richtextbox then the issue happens

Comment: Then there must be some error occurring that you are suppressing or not seeing